# Need a sound to play every second if a button is toggled

Tags: java, android

I have a toggle button and i need the 'mp' sound to play every second if that button is toggled.The code below is what i tried and it does play the sound every second but the button stops responding so i can't turn it off.

```
    ToggleButton btn = findViewById(R.id.button);
    final MediaPlayer mp  = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beat);

    btn.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked) {
            while (isChecked) {
                mp.start();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Thread.sleep on main thread will make your app hang. Check out Handler.postDelayed. Don't forget to remove the callback in onPause (and move adding the callback to onResume).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to another question and modified it to fit my needs and now it works perfectly.Here is the solution/code.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;
int delayMillis;
Handler handler;
Runnable runnable;
private boolean isToggleChecked;
private ToggleButton toggleButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    toggleButton = findViewById(R.id.button);

    handler = new Handler();
    runnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mediaPlayer.start();

        }
    };


    toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked) {
                isToggleChecked = true;
                toggleMediaPlayer();
            }
            else {
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer=null;
                handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
                isToggleChecked = false;
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if (isToggleChecked) {
        toggleButton.setChecked(true);
    }
    else {
        toggleButton.setChecked(false);
    }
}

private void toggleMediaPlayer(){
    if(mediaPlayer != null){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer=null;
        handler.removeCallbacks(runnable);
    }else{
        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beat);
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });

        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                delayMillis = 1000;
                handler.postDelayed(runnable,delayMillis);
            }
        });

    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never use `Thread.sleep(1000)` it is the terrible thing you can do to the app. Your app is not
      responsding because you are putting Main thread of app to sleep.

I have created this class for you for desmonstration. you can tweak is further to your needs.

```
  private Handler soundHandler = new Handler();
  private int delay = 1000;
  private Runnable soundRunnable;
  private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
  private boolean isToggleChecked;

  @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ToggleButton toggleButton = findViewById(R.id.button);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.beat);

    toggleButton.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
      @Override public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton compoundButton, boolean isChecked){
        isToggleChecked = isChecked;
        if(isChecked){
          playSound();
        }else {
          stopSound();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  @Override protected void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(isToggleChecked){
      playSound();
    }
  }

  // this will make sure sound stops when app stops or goes in background
  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    soundHandler.removeCallbacks(soundRunnable);
    super.onPause();
  }

  private void playSound(){
    soundHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
      public void run() {
        soundRunnable = this;
        if(mediaPlayer != null) {
          mediaPlayer.start();
        }
        soundHandler.postDelayed(soundRunnable, delay);
      }
    }, delay);
  }

  private void stopSound(){
    if(mediaPlayer != null){
      if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        soundHandler.removeCallbacks(soundRunnable);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: It works but it's very glitchy. Sometimes the sound doesn't play. Sometimes turning off the button doesn't turn off the sound and it just continues on playing every second.Also tapping the button quickly multiple times just stops the sound and you have to restart the app in rder to be able to start it again.

Comment: of course it is not a perfect solution, I just wanted to give you an idea how it works, you can tweak it in such a way that create  `mediaPlayer` in `playSound()` and release it in `stopSound()`